# Working of call stack when async/await is used

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, event-loop

How does the Call Stack behave when async/await functions are used ?

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() { // taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

const asyncFuntion=async()=>{
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.info("asyncFuntion finish, result is: ", result);
}

const first = async()=>{
    await asyncFuntion();
    console.log('first completed');
        debugger;
}

const second = ()=>{
    console.log('second completed');
        debugger;
}

function main(){
    first();
    second();
}


main();
```

In the above code, when the first breakpoint is encountered in second(), I could see that the call stack contained main() and second(). And during the second breakpoint in first(), the call stack contained main() and first().

What happened to first() during the first breakpoint. Where is it pushed ? Assuming that the asyncFunction() takes some time to complete.

Someone please help.

Comment: The problem comes up when  you are mixing `synchronous` and `asynchronous` functions together. I am not very sure tough, but I can imagine, `main()` starts, and pushes `first()` to callstack `x` since it's `async`. Immediately after `first()` was invoked, `second()` is called and pushed to a different callstack, cuz `sync`.  I usually imagine `async` funcions to myself as some sort of threads.

Comment: It seems your answer is logical. But, wont this contradict the fact that the JS engine has a single call stack?

Comment: Yes, `nodes` has a single `eventloop`.  But the `eventloop` is just the final executioner. I think there'll still be different `callstacks` or something like queues. In the end, the eventloop takes all these queues and just executes them in some order. I have not enough knowledge to answer this question correctly , so I just put this as comment.

Comment: Yes. I understand that event loop takes callbacks from queues and pushed it into the stack. But, since using await will block the execution of the first(), the function should exist in the call stack itself, right?.

Comment: I think, you cannot call it `callstack`. I think it's just the stacktrace. I guess this is handled more low-level.`

Comment: Ok. Even though, it would be nice if someone could give an exact idea on how the stack works when using async/await

Comment: @ZeeshanShamsuddeen - I tried to explain that in my answer, If there's anything that you'd like me to clarify please drop a comment on it.

Answer (score 21):

First off, when you get to the breakpoint you hit in `second`, `first` has already executed and is no longer on the stack.

When we go into `first`, we instantly hit an `await asyncFunction()`. This tells JavaScript to not block on the result of the call, but feel free to go looking for something else to do while we're waiting. What does Javascript do?

Well, first of all, it does call `asyncFunction()`. This returns a promise, and will have started some asynchronous process that will later resolve it. Now we can't continue with the next line of `first` (ie, the `console.log('first completed')`) because our `await` means we can't carry on until the promise was fulfilled, so we need to suspend execution here and go find something else to do with our free time.

So, we look up the stack. We're still in the `first()` call from main, and now we can just return a promise from that call, which we will resolve when the asynchronous execution completes. `main` ignores that promise return value, so we continue right with `second()`. Once we've executed `second`, we look back to whatever called that, and carry on with synchronous execution in the way everyone would expect.

Then, at some point in the future, our promise fulfills. Maybe it was waiting on an API call to return. Maybe it was waiting on the database to reply back to it. In our example, it was waiting for a 2s timeout. Whatever it was waiting for, it now is ready to be dealt with, and we can un-suspend the `first` call and continue executing there. It's not "called" from `main` - internally the function is picked back up, just like a callback, but crucially is called with a completely new stack, which will be destroyed once we're done calling the remainder of the function.

Given that we're in a new stack, and have long since left the 'main' stack frame, how do `main` and `first` end up on the stack again when we hit the breakpoint inside it?

For a long time, if you ran your code inside debuggers, the simple answer was that they wouldn't. You'd just get the function you were in, and the debugger would tell you it had been called from "asynchronous code", or something similar.

However, nowadays some debuggers can follow awaited code back to the promise that it is resolving (remember, `await` and `async` are *mostly* just syntactic sugar on top of promises). In other words, when your awaited code finishes, and the "promise" under the hood resolves, your debugger helpfully figures out what the stack "should" look like. What it shows doesn't actually bear much resemblance to how the engine ended up calling the function - after all, it was called out of the event loop. However, I think it's a helpful addition, enabling us all to keep the mental model of our code much simpler than what's actually going on!

Some further reading on how this works, which covers much more detail than I can here:

- [Zero-cost async stack traces](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Sy_kBIJGP0XT34V1CV3nkWya4TwYx9L3Yv45LdGB6Q/edit#heading=h.g73wf9gxqj2u)
- [Asynchronous stack traces](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-stack-traces)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still have some questions.

I understand that JS will not wait for first() to complete, but starts asyncFunction(),then pops first() out of stack, and then goes to second(). But then, who takes care of first() and it's remaining execution ? Is a new stack created for it? or are callbacks used? if so, how?

Comment: @ZeeshanShamsuddeen - Updated the answer, hope it's more clear. I'd suggest looking up the details of how the JavaScript Event Loop works if you're looking for a great amount of detail about that though - there's plenty of good answers on here already and I'd rather not get too close to repeating them.

Comment: Thank you for that @Hecksa. But, I thought Event Loop only checks the Callbacks queues, Micro Task queues etc for any task that is ready to be pushed to the call Stack. Did you mean the callback queue?

Comment: @ZeeshanShamsuddeen - You're absolutely right - promises queue microtasks once they are resolved. I was trying to keep pretty high-level, but you're absolutely right to point out the difference. So, once asyncFunction is done, a microTask is queued. When JS is ready to deal with that task, it will create a new stack to run it within. At that point, certain debuggers are able to follow through the context of the underlying promise to make it seem like you are within the original stack, but you're not.

Comment: @ZeeshanShamsuddeen - To be honest, if you know the difference between Micro Tasks and Tasks and the Event Loop, you'd probably be better served looking at the links I posted, or possibly https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/ That link has a great step-by-step animation going through this kind of problem. They will do a better job of explaining the details than I'll ever be able to!

Comment: Thank @Hecksa. In regards with your answer, if JS creates an internal stack, it contradicts the fact that JS has only 1 Stack. right?. Actually, there are a lot of articles and I am really confused among them. Some articles say something on event loops, event tables, event queues etc and some say only about event loops and callback queues.

Comment: @ZeeshanShamsuddeen - Ignoring Workers, It would be accurate to say that JS only has 1 *active* stack at any given time, but not that it only has one stack. Callbacks having their own stack doesn't mean JS is still running the normal stack at the same time, JS is just swapping to a different stack temporarily, because clearly it can't execute an asynchronous callback inside the current stack, as it would make no sense at all.

Comment: If there's something you're confused about regarding all the event loop stuff, maybe that'd be best raised as a separate question, I think it's a little beyond the scope of this one to go really deeply into how the event loop is split up etc. Feel free to link in here if you do create that question.

Comment: Very good answer for this rather complex topic. You should replace "signal got sent" with "execution has been completed". Signals are used this ping processes for termination and stuff. Execution completed does not mean the result was successfully acquired.

Comment: "*we have to sort out asyncFunction. We throw that function call into the event loop. That is to say, we put it in a queue of "things to do when we have time"*" - no, that's not how it works. The call `asyncFunction()` is executed immediately, normally, and returns a promise (magically by `async` or otherwise). It doesn't matter how that promise is constructed. Then, the `await` does hook onto the promise like a `.then()` handler, to continue executing the function when the promise settles.

Comment: @Bergi - appreciate the correction - please feel free to make an edit if you can think of a way to correct that paragraph that's clear + reasonably concise. I'm a little short for time right now and can't immediately find a nice way to fix the inaccuracy.

Comment: Done. I hope it's still reasonable concise :-)

Comment: Looks great, thanks for improving the answer :)