# Does a async function gets added to the callstack?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

If i declare a function like below:

```
function a(){
   //do something
}
```

And if i execute it with `a()` it gets putted onto the top of the callstack and gets popped of when its finished. While the function is in the callstack the main thread is blocked and cant do other things until the callstack is empty.
But what happens exactly with an `async` function?

if i do:

```
async function b() {
   //do something
}
```

The function returns an promise and does not block the main thread. Does this mean this function gets passed to the web API instead of the callstack? and then after its done it gets passed to the callback que and then gets passed to the callstack and so that we can execute the callback function?

```
b.then(function() {
   //do something after finish
})
```

Comment: Possible answer, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241258/working-of-call-stack-when-async-await-is-used

Comment: What do you mean by "*gets passed to the web API*"?

Comment: @Bergi what i meant is that promises are passed to the microtask que and not the web API. (i hope thas correct) So i thougth that async functions are also passed to the microtasks que?

Comment: No, I guess "*web API*" doesn't mean what you think. And no, while promise callbacks are *scheduled* via a task queue, when they are executed they're still put on the call stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `async function`s will be on the call stack during their execution just like normal functions. You can consider the desugaring of the `await` keyword:

```
function log(x) {
  console.log("at "+x);
}
function delay(t) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
async function example() {
  log(1);
  await delay(50);
  log(2);
  return 3;
}
function example2() {
  log(1);
  return delay(50).then(function cont() {
    log(2);
    return 3;
  })
}
```

An `example()` call works exactly like an `example2()` call. The called function gets pushed on the stack, calls `log(1)` which gets pushed on the stack and runs, when that returns (gets popped from the stack) it calls `delay(50)` which gets put on the stack and runs, and so on. Now, when the `await` operator is evaluated, the async function will take the operand promise, attach callbacks using a `.then()` call, and then *return from the `example()` call* a promise for the eventual completion of the function body. So when it reaches the `await` keyword, it gets popped from the stack, and the caller may continue running synchronous code (that will typically involve doing something with the returned promise).

Then, when the promise is resolved (in the above example, when the timeout is hit), jobs are scheduled to run the attached `then` callbacks. They might have to wait for the event loop to become idle (the callstack to become empty), and then when the promise job starts the code is put on the callstack again. In `example2`, this is the `cont` function that will get called, in the `async function` it will be continuation of the `example` body, where it left off at the `await`. In both cases, it calls `log(2)` which gets pushed on the stack and runs, and when that returns (gets popped from the stack) the `return 3` statement is executed which resolves the promise and pops the execution context from the stack, leaving it empty.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, excellent answer +1, so, will ANY asynchronous function (like callbacks of a .then) ALWAYS RETURN BACK to the callstack of the main (and only) javascript thread when its time to execute comes?

Comment: @Daniel So by "asynchronous function" you mean the asynchronously executed part of the code, not the function that starts the asynchronous action? Yes, it always executes on the normal call stack, with just the event loop (and possibly some library code) below. But I'm not sure what you mean by "*return back to the callstack*".

Comment: hi @Bergi when I say  "asynchronous function" I mean the asynchronously executed part of the code

Comment: Then yes, it runs on the same "main" call stack as everything else, and like any other code on a call stack, returns to the stack frame below it (which for a `then` callback or code in an `async` function after an `await` is typically the promise job itself, which then ends and leaves space for the next job to be executed).

Comment: One last question @Bergi, is the asynchronously executed part of the code delegated to the WEB API so as not to block the javascript thread or WHERE IS THAT MYSTERY PLACE where it is put?

Comment: I understand that it ends up running in the main callstack, but before reaching the main callstack, where is it located?

Comment: "Asynchronously executed" here just means that it is executed *later*, after the web api is done with some (background) processing. But while the JS code is executed, it's blocking like any other JS code. It reaches the call stack only when it will actually begin executing - until then it's just a function that is not currently executing.

Comment: I think the "mystery place" you are talking about refers to the processing of the web api, which can e.g. happen in some background thread. Or just use asynchronous operating system apis itself (especially for networking). And when that processing is done, it fires an event or resolves a promise, which schedules the js code to run.

Comment: the processing that the web api does (in the case of promises/async/await) is ONLY resolving the promise itself to get a result, the what-to-do part (the part of the code that executes asynchronously) when you have that result will be PROCESSED-DONE by javascript in the main callstack, right? Sorry, that's where I'm still confused about what each part does @Bergi

Comment: I just need to understand what the web api does, thanks again. What JS does I got your point.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*resolving the promise to get a result*". The web api resolves the promise to **provide** a result to the JS code. "*the what-to-do part of the code when you have that result will be processed by javascript in the main callstack*" - still yes.

Comment: `The web api resolves the promise to provide a result to the JS code`. Now I understand, thanks. There JS knows that the web api finished (has a result) thanks to the event loop, right?

Comment: Yes. Resolving the promise schedules the promise reactions (`then` callbacks, `await` resumptions) on the job queue.

Comment: thank you very much @Bergi, now I understand. I always thought that ALL THE CODE involved with promises, async/await was processed in the web api. Marked AS USEFUL RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

it does go onto the call stack, when its time for the async function to run it gets moved off of the call stack until the function is either fulfilled.or rejected.  at this point it get moved into the callback queue while all other synchronous functions can continue to execute off of the callstack, then when the callstack is empty, the event loop looks in the callback queue for anything else that needs to be executed.  if there is anything in the callback queue the event loop pushes the callback into the call stack to execute.

Comment: "*when its time for the async function to run*" - please be more specific about what you mean here, as the current wording makes it wrong.